# Substitute value in a formula using trigger

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a project which has a couple of math calculations which has to be done based on the data fed

I have written a trigger in SQL SERVER to compute this value. I used REPLACE() to replace the variables with values and got the below

For example :

```
Value = 100 +a - (b*10)

a=1
b=2
```

I get Value = 100 + 1 -(2*10)

Expected output is  Value = 81

I use the below query :

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(Value,'a',1),'b',2) FROM Formula
```

Is there any better way to get this done ?

Comment: I recommend against this kind of design. The only way you can derive the values is by using dynamic SQL If you provide the literal string `'100 +a - (b*10)'` for the column `value`, and then use your `REPLACE` expression, you get `'100 + 1 -(2*10)`, not `81`, because `value` is still a `varchar`, and `REPLACE` doesn't cause a literal string to be interpreted as an expression and then derived. This is very likely an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Better way to get what done? Seems to me that you should ask your teacher, your tutor, your team, your superior - someone that knows what you are trying to accomplish and can help with a direction.You mix string and numeric literals - which is a sign that you have not mastered basic tsql. To successfully implement dynamic tsql, you need to master the basics first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than `REPLACE`, you could store the formula as a parameterized query expression and pass the values as parameters:

```
DECLARE @value int;
DECLARE @formula nvarchar(MAX) = N'SET @Value = 100 + @a - (@b * 10);';
EXEC sp_executesql @formula, N'@value int OUTPUT, @a int, @b int', @a = 1, @b = 2, @value = @value OUTPUT;
PRINT @value;
```

Comment: Thanks ! But My formula table has more than 1000 such values which will be fetched based on the id passed. Plus, it was just an example to use a,b . There are around 10 such fields whose value will be fetched from another table.

Comment: @charanya, what formula table? I see no mention of it in your question. My answer is just an example. You would need to apply this method to your actual situation.